# How to init null-objects in array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, null, initialization

```
public static MyType mtOrders;    
public static MyType mtCustomers;    
public static MyType mtItems;    
public static MyType mtGroups;    
public static MyType mtDelieverAddresses;    
public static MyType mtVendors;    
public static MyType mtOrderItems;    
public static MyType mtPrims;        

public final static MyType[] xTable = {mtCustomers, mtGroups, mtItems, mtOrders,
                        mtDelieverAddresses, mtVendors, mtOrderItems, mtPrims};

for (int i = 0; i < xTables.length; i++) {    
  xTable[i] = new MyType();
}
```

After executing `xTable`'s elements are initialized, but `mtOrders`... `mtPrims` are null!

I understand why this is so, but I can not think how I initialize the objects in the loop.

I do not want to do this:

```
mtOrders = new MyType();
mtCustomers = new MyType();
...
mtPrims = new MyType();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xTable` and that series of static variables are different *references*, that *might* point on the same object, but cannot be used to modify each other. Namely, they can both be used to modify the same *object*, but having one point on an object will not make the other point on that object as well.

I don't quite understand your actual goal. Best I can offer is to use some intermediate class they will all point to. So `mtOrders` will not be a `MyType`, but a `MyTypeRef`, which will have a `MyType` field. Then, do initialize it to a new `MyTypeRef`, and use the loop to set the `MyType` objects in all the refs. Since both the static variables and the `xTable` entries will point on the same `MyTypeRef`, setting the `MyType` field on one will affect the other as well.

IMO, using that loop instead of initializing each separate variable looks like tighter code, but it doesn't work. Just write a few more lines of code, so it's not as pretty but actually works.

Comment: Well, I'm not crazy about this solution, because it adds an extra wrapper to every variable just to bypass some initialization issue. But it's your code...

Comment: My initialization really much complex, than i showed. I thinking, that simplier add new var to array, than copy-paste a lot lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't have a way of initializing a reference variable other than assigning to it. You can perhaps get close to what you want with a map:

```
public static final String myOrders = "mtOrders";
// etc.

public final static Map<String, MyType> xTable;

static {
    HashMap<String, MyType> table = new HashMap<String, MyType>();
    String[] keys = { myOrders, . . . }
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
        table.put(keys[i], new MyType());
    }
    xTable = Collections.unmodifiableMap(table);
}
```

Then you can get at individual elements by:

```
MyType orders = xTable.get(myOrders);
```

If this doesn't meet your needs, you'll just have to assign each field individually.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll do as I suggested by eran.